# How to convert excel file from SASContenrServer to dataset in SAS

Tags: excel, sas, sas-macro

I have some excel files in SASContentServer that I want to convert into dataset.

this is the code that I'm using

```
*filename out "/app/sas/test.xlsx";
filename out temp;

%let model_rk_val = "10013";
%let model_id_val = "model";

proc http 
method="get"
url="http://server:port/SASContentServer/repository/default/sasdav/Products/SASModelRisk/ModelRiskMgtMid-Tier/Content/customObject1/&model_rk_val/&model_id_val..xlsx"
webUserName="sasmrmad"
webPassword="xxxxxxx"
out=out;
run;

*libname mip_in "/app/sas/folder";

proc import datafile = out
    DBMS=xlsx
    out=mip_in.vars;
    sheet='vars';       
RUN;

proc import datafile = out
    DBMS=xlsx
    out=mip_in.outest;
    sheet='outest';     
RUN;
```

if i use `filename out temp` then system gives me error that tempfile.xlsx is missing because filename out temp crates a temporary file in temp folder without any extension and `DBMS=xlsx` looks for a file with extention of .xlsx and because my temp file has no extension it gives error.

if i create a file like test.xlsx and use `filename out "/app/sas/test.xlsx";`system says that file is damaged even if I create a new excel file there the error is same that file is damaged or file format or extension is not valid.

Kindly can you tell me that how can i resolve this issue or is there any other approach that I can use to convert my excel files to dataset?

Comment: Couple of questions.  1. Can you open the file in Excel after the download?  2. Please paste the actual ERROR you receive.  3. on the Linux console, do `head /app/sas/test.xlsx` and make sure you have what looks like an Excel file -- add the results here.

Comment: 1) No i cant open excel sheet.

Comment: ERROR: Error opening XLSX file -> /app/sastest.xlsx .  It is either not an Excel spreadsheet or it is damaged.  
 Error code=8014900A (with filename out "/app/sas/test.xlsx" )

Comment: @DomPazz you mean file out "head /app/sas/test.xlsx";

Comment: I assume you have access to the system OS.  From the command prompt, type `head /app/sas/test.xlsx`.  Alternatively, open the file in a text editor and see what it looks like. If it is an XLSX file, then you shouldn't be able to read it.  The fact that Excel cannot open the file tells me this is not an issue with the XLSX engine, but something with file creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead of FILENAME TEMP to create a temp file with a specific extension:

```
    filename out "%sysfunc(getoption(WORK))/test.xlsx";
```

And check out [the HTTP_TOKENAUTH option](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n197g47i7j66x9n15xi0gaha8ov6.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en) instead of using webUsername and webPassword.

It's not always obvious when the HTTP call fails. Check the value of &SYS_PROCHTTP_STATUS_CODE macro variable to see that you get the expected "200" code as well (SAS 9.4M3 and later).  Or use the [HEADEROUT= option](http://documentation.sas.com/?docsetId=proc&docsetTarget=n1guza108as4zdn10b4wns869w5b.htm&docsetVersion=9.4&locale=en#n1guza108as4zdn10b4wns869w5b) to write the header response details to a file that you can check.

Comment: Sir what does this function do? filename out "%sysfunc(getoption(WORK))/test.xlsx";

Comment: That function gets the current WORK folder path and appends the filename (test.xlsx).  And then allocates the fileref to that path.  The result is a file with an XLSX extension that PROC IMPORT can recognize, as long as the file contents are for a true XLSX file.